# Adding a sequential number using ArcGIS field calculator to string file and keeping the 0 in front of the number?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, field-calculator, python-parser

I want to know if anyone has a code to count +1 starting at a certain number for Field Calc. ArcGIS. (I.e. 04312, 04313) It also must keep the 0 in front.

```
rec=0
def autoIncrement():
 global rec
 pStart = 040150117669
 pInterval = 1
 if (rec == 0): 
  rec = pStart 
 else: 
  rec = rec + pInterval 
 return rec

    str(autoIncrement( )).zfill(12)
```

parsing error syntaxerror:invalid token (line 4)

Comment: Replace 040150117669 by 40150117669

Answer (score 1):

Use block

```
rec=0
def autoIncrement():
 global rec
 pStart = 1 #adjust start value, if req'd 
 pInterval = 1 #adjust interval value, if req'd
 if (rec == 0): 
  rec = pStart 
 else: 
  rec = rec + pInterval 
 return rec
```

Call it using:

str(autoIncrement(  )).zfill(5)

It will work on **text** field

Comment: you can update your question

Comment: this doesn't keep the 0 in front of the number. the 0 is crucial. any suggestions?

Comment: are you doing it on text field?